# Bootstrap Font Awesome Badge with number

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a Navigation with a bell Icon. I would like to add a badge which contains a number on the top right of the Icon (like in a few Android apps). I found some Blogs which accomplish this adding the number in css, but I Need to add the number on the Server side so doing something like this:

```
<span>$number</span>
```

Would be better.

The layout Looks like this so far:

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="navbar-inquiries-dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                // here add badge????
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-item dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbar-inquiries-dropdown">
               <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('inquiry.index') }}">
                        Requests
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: @Abinthaha I would like to know how to add a badge on the top right of my Icon with a number

Comment: You can add it and use `position` to align it over your icon

Answer (score 5):

FontAwesome has this in their documentation.

Take a look at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js and find  *Layering, Text, & Counters*

SVG with JS requires you to use the JS version of FontAwesome. Latest CDN link can be found here: https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js

```
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato">1,419</span>
</span>`
```

You can position the counter using the following classes:
`fa-layers-bottom-left`, `fa-layers-bottom-right`, `fa-layers-top-left` and the default `fa-layers-top-right`

Comment: Does not fit the ball Icon is a square form and the number is right next to the bell Icon with a square form aswell

Comment: @Jaan I've updated my answer. You need the JS version of FontAwesome to do this. https://jsfiddle.net/02Lt813g/

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this and let me know if it was what you wanted

```
<i class="fas fa-bell badge-wrapper">
  <span class='badge badge-secondary'>21</span>
</i>
```

Style

```
.badge-wrapper {
     position: relative;
 }

 .badge {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: -5px;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: #ddd;
 }
```

Comment: Using `bootstrap`?

Comment: still not visible

Comment: Check now, edited. Botostrap4 uses two classes `badge` and  `badge-secondary` to display the badge. The first example was using b3

Answer (score 0):

Favorit
                        
                        
                             Pesanan
                        
                        
                            2 Notification

```css
.badge {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: xx-small;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: var(--orange);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
      <a href="" class="font-weight-bolder text-success nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bell"><span class='badge badge-pill'>2</span></i> Notification</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  
</body>

</html>
```